# How to make the content-container div expand to fill the remaining vertical space Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm quite new at webpage design and I'm working on a web page layout where I have sidebar on the whole left side, and then a navbar on the right, divided by two columns that show content. One of them, `content-container` is where I want to display some dynamic content. I want this div to fill the remaining vertical space between the header and bottom because I want to add a footer on the second column (top right) and have an infinite scroll on the first column. However, I've tried several CSS approaches, and none of them seem to work.

I've tried setting the height of the content-container div to 100%, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's what I've tried:

- Setting `height: 100%` on the content container column, as well as its parent elements (html, body, and wrapper). This did not work, as the column still did not expand to fill the available vertical space.
- Adding the `align-items: stretch` property to the parent flex container. This also did not work, as the content container column remained the same size as before.

Can anyone suggest a solution for making the content container column expand to fill the available vertical space without causing it to continue expanding past the bottom of the viewport? Is there a better approach to achieving the desired result?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```css
* {
  /* variables */
  --main-color: #2a2d2f;
  /* variable establecida */
  --border-color: dimgrey;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  color: var(--main-color);
  /* utilizando la variable */
}

.page-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #b7dad6;
}


/*  Sidebar */

#sidebar {
  max-width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: dimgrey 0.05rem solid;
}

.logo-container {
  padding-left: 2rem;
}


/* remove link effect */

.sidebar a:link,
.sidebar a:hover,
.sidebar a:visited,
.sidebar a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--main-color);
  /* utilizando la variable */
}

.sidebar-element {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 1.2rem;
}

.sidebar-element:hover {
  background-color: #cec9c9;
}

.sidebar-element .active {
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* content */

content-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #b7dad6;
}


/* Navbar */

.navbar-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: #b5dffd;
  height: 3rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: var(--border-color) 0.05rem solid;
}

.extra-content-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: #b5dffd;
  height: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  border-left: var(--border-color) 0.05rem solid;
}


/*   ICONS */

.bi {
  color: var(--main-color);
  /* utilizando la variable */
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- <link href="sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

<!-- Bootstrap Icons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<!-- Fonts -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet'>


<div class="page-wrapper d-flex container-fluid bg-gray">

  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div class="navbar d-flex align-items-end flex-column mb-3" id="sidebar">
    <div class="container-sm py-5 mt1 logo-container">
      <a class="" href="#" , style="margin-bottom: 0px">
        <img src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="Bootstrap" height="40">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar container-sm py-2 px-2">

      <div class="sidebar-element flex-grow-1">
        <i class="bi bi-binoculars-fill"></i>
        <a class="active" href="#">Explore</a>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-element flex-grow-1">
        <i class="bi bi-bookmark-star"></i>
        <a href="#">Bookmarks</a>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-element flex-grow-1">
        <i class="bi bi-person"></i>
        <a href="#">Profile</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar container-sm mt-auto py-2">
      <div class="sidebar-element flex-grow-1">
        <i class="bi bi-gear"></i>
        <a href="#">Configuration</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--  Content  -->
  <div class="content-container container text-center">
    <div class="row flex-grow-1 d-flex" style="background-color: #ec1b1b">
      <div class="col navbar-container" style="background-color: #8cdae7">
        NAVBAR
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row card-main-container" style="background-color: darkkhaki">
      <div class="col-8">
        Main content with infinite scroll here
      </div>
      <div class="extra-content-container col-4">
        <div>
          some extra content plus a the footer on the bottom
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I'm confused. The div with `content-container` already _is_ full height, and there's no header or footer outside of it. Also, what you're calling the footer is configured as a column _inside_ that div. Have you looked at it with your browser's document inspector? Please revise to make your goal more clear.

Comment: That's the point. I guess is wired, but I'm trying to add the footer on the right column. The lay out would be: sidebar with menu, navbar with search. Two Colima of content left with inf. Scroll and right with some content plus footer. I want the footer of the right column to be on the bottom. And understand why it does not do that now.

Comment: FYI, you have a comma in your markup. That's invalid.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe trying this, just put your dimentions of height:

```
<div id="div" class="card" style="overflow-y: auto;height: calc(90vh - 50px); display:'';"> <!-- your HTML--> </div>
```

Comment: Why should I do that? This looks like a random answer to me...

Comment: Inline styles are bad practice, and Bootstrap provides much of what you're doing as classes.

Comment: The inline styles are just for debugging purposes. Ans I'm aware I can use paddings, margins and other style as bootstrap class. Just, as said much new to it and need to really understand it. Planning to move all to scss when it looks as expected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).